# Golang SQL query variable substituion

Tags: sql, database, oracle, go

I have sql query that needs variable substitution for better consumption of my [go-kit](https://github.com/go-kit/kit) service.

I have `dep` & `org` as user inputs which are part of my rest service, for instance: `dep = 'abc'` and `org = 'def'`.

I've tried few things like:

```
rows, err := db.Query(
    "select name from table where department='&dep' and organisation='&org'",
)
```

And:

```
rows, err := db.Query(
    "select name from table where department=? and organisation=?", dep , org,
)
```

That led to error: `sql: statement expects 0 inputs; got 2`

Only hard-coded values work and substitution fails .

I haven't found much help from oracle blogs regarding this and wondering if there is any way to approach this.

Comment: The right way is `db.Query()` or `db.Prepare()` with `stmt.Exec()`. But `db.Query()` does not return only error, whats is your driver? Please, complete with a sample of code with `db` variable creation. Reference: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query

Comment: here is my ora driver - https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8

Comment: func NewOracleConnection(cfg config.Config, log log.Logger) (Connection, error) {
 var err error
 o := &Oracle{
  Driver:        cfg.DB.Driver,
  ConnectString: cfg.DB.ConnectString,
  logger:        log,
 }
 o.Db, err = sql.Open(o.Driver, o.ConnectString)
 if err != nil {
  log.Log("event", "connecting to database", "err", err.Error())
 }
 return o, err
}

Comment: i have tried db.query & Exec. what's interesting is sqlplus client works fine for the same query with variable substitution but fails with this driver

Comment: For that driver it seems to be `:N` (https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8/blob/master/oci8Sql_test.go#L1149) where `N` is the position of the parameter. So in your case something like this should work: `db.Query("select name from table where department = :1 and organisation = :2", dep, org)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Parameter Placeholder Syntax (reference: http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html )

> The syntax for placeholder parameters in prepared statements is
>   database-specific. For example, comparing MySQL, PostgreSQL, and
>   Oracle:

```
MySQL               PostgreSQL            Oracle
=====               ==========            ====== 
WHERE col = ?       WHERE col = $1        WHERE col = :col 
VALUES(?, ?, ?)     VALUES($1, $2, $3)    VALUES(:val1, :val2, :val3)
```

For oracle you need to use :dep, :org as placeholders.

Answer (score 3):

As @dakait stated, on your prepare statement you should use `:` placeholders.

So, for completeness, you would get it working with something like:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

// Output is an example struct
type Output struct {
    Name string
}

const (
    dep = "abc"
    org = "def"
)

func main() {

    query := "SELECT name from table WHERE department= :1 and organisation = :2"

    q, err := db.Prepare(query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer q.Close()

    var out Output

    if err := q.QueryRow(dep, org).Scan(&out.Name); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(out.Name)

}
```